# Hovered Navigation bar not aligning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hoverable navigation bar that when you hover the relavent links appear and it seems not to be aligning underneath and when the position is not absolute, it pushes the other links aside after hover

**Html**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testsitestyle.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div id="nav">
     <ul>
        <li id="drop2">Home<li/>
      <ul>
        <li>Number</li>
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
    
    </li>
    <li>Knowledge</li>
    <li>Qoutes</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Css**

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    
}


#nav {
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#nav li {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:40px;
        margin-right:40px;
        padding:30px;
        vertical-align:top;
        border:2px solid red;
        position:relative;
        
        
}


#drop2 ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0px;
    display:none;   
    position:absolute;

    border:2px solid red;
}

#drop2 ul li {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
        ``padding:30px;
        margin:0px;
        margin-top:25px;        
}
#drop2:hover>ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've placed red boarders around them all to show you what i'm trying to create.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjdvt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This, based in part on Thoughtbot's Refills/Empties (http://empties.bourbon.io/) should get you started. If you're concerned with creating a responsive navigation menu (one that works well on mobile as well as desktop), I'd recommend looking at their code examples to get yourself sorted.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
nav ul {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li.nav-link a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hover-menu {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
.hover-menu .hover-menu-item {
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.hover-menu .submenu {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.hover-menu .submenu li {
  display: block;
}
.hover-menu .submenu li a {
  text-align: left;
  width: 12em;
}
.hover-menu .submenu .submenu {
  left: 12em;
  top: 0;
}
.hover-menu:focus > .submenu,
.hover-menu:hover > .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link hover-menu">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hover-menu-item">Home</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Number</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">One</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Knowledge</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Quotes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contract</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have no clue what this is, sorry, could you explain further

Comment: Does the code snippet above do what you intended? Which bit do you have questions about?